# Estimating the Expectation

Tags: statistics

I don't have the solution to the underlined part of the question and I was wondering if my thoughts are indeed correct:

[image]

Importance sampling works best when $w(x):=\frac{\tilde{f}_X(x)}{\phi(x)}\approx1$

As x increases over the support  $\frac{\tilde{f}_X(x)}{\phi(x)}$  also increases, hence more weight than is desired is given to the upper values of x and hence the mean is skewed to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I hope I get this question right. [Rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)  comes to my mind.

We have a set $X=(x_1,...,x_n)$ with $n$ large.

From the left plot, we see that $\phi(x)\cdot M > \tilde f_X(x)$ for $M>1$ but not too large.

For the rejection method we need samples $u$ from a uniform distribution and $x$ from $\phi(x)$ which are exactly the $x_i$ from the set $X$.

From the set $X$ we accept all samples for which $u<\tilde f_X(x)/(M\phi(x))$. We call the accepted samples $x_i^*$ and the given set $X^*$. Then the mean of  $X^*$ gives the expected value for $\tilde f_X(x)$.

The efficiency of the rejection method depends on the quality of the upper bound $\phi$. But the plots suggest, that $\phi$ is a good upper bound with 
\begin{align}
\int \phi(x)\cdot M \, dx \approx \int \tilde f_X(x)\,dx
\end{align}
Define 
\begin{align}
P=\frac{\int \phi(x)\cdot M \, dx }{ \int \tilde f_X(x)\,dx} 
\end{align}
$P$ is the probability that we accept a sample (so $\dim(X^*)\approx P\dim(X)$).
Since $P$ is close to one, we can use most of the points of the original sample for $\tilde f_X$. Thus the method is efficient.

Problem: Right now, I don't know how to handle the fact, that $\tilde f_X$ is not normalized.

I hope I didn't miss the point completely.